# Facebook Api não recebe a permissão de Email

Tags: facebook, login, facebook-sdk, api

Ola, estou com um serio problema com o API do Facebook, tenho tentado obter o email para meu sistema de OAuth, porém o api retornava nulo, fazendo o processo de debug descobri que na verdade o APP não esta solicitando a permissão de Email. Alguem sabe o que posso fazer?

Aqui são as permissões do API:
[image: Permissão no API - Developers.facebook.com]

Aqui são as permissões requisitadas durante o acesso:
[image: Request by Login]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

Basicamente, assim que o login for efetuado, irá realizar a chamada no método callLoginMethod() que irá exibir as informações.

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="email,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_location,user_location" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" onlogin="callLoginMethod();" login_text="Entrar com o Facebook"> </div>
```

Javascript:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : SEU_APP_ID,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
  };



 (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function basicAPIRequest() {
    FB.api('/me', 
        {fields: "id,picture,birthday,email,first_name,gender,name,location,hometown"}, 
        function(response) {
          console.log('Resposta:', response);

        }
    );
  }

  function callLoginMethod() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            basicAPIRequest();
        } else {
            FB.login();
        }
    }); 
  }
```

Comment: Certo Thiago, o problema não esta no codigo. Ja fiz o teste com a SDK e com a API em PHP, o problema é que quando você aceita o uso do app ele não pede tais informações, somente o nome, sexo e idade que são dados de perfis publicos. O que eu  não consigo entender é pq ele não libera o pedido para o Email, sendo que pelo developers.facebook  no meu app mostra como liberado.

Comment: Vá no facebook do usuário, exclua o aplicativo e repita o processo. Eu acabei de fazer uma página, com um aplicativo recém criado ( que no caso eu não tenho permissão de nada, apenas e-mail, nome e id.) e utilizei o código acima pra receber as informações. 

Meu aplicativo nem está publico, está em modo de desenvolvimento e só funciona corretamente por enquanto com o perfil do desenvolvedor.

Comment: Você colocou as permissões de e-mail no Scope da função? coloque o código na página.

Comment: Realmente Thiago, foi um erro meu no Scope...Obrigado pela ajuda!